# maclaurin series of $f(x)=xe^{-x}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm not sure how to do: $$f(x)=xe^{-x}$$I did this one so far:
$$ f(x) = x^2 \cos x = x^2 \left( 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!} - \dfrac{x^6}{6!} +\dfrac{x^8}{8!} \dots \right) = x^2 - \dfrac{x^4}{2!} + \dfrac{x^6}{4!} - \dfrac{x^8}{6!} +\dfrac{x^{10}}{6!} \dots $$

i know that the maclaurin series for $f(x)=e^x= 1 + x+ \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^3}{3!} - \dfrac{x^4}{4!}\dots$

Comment: Please check again your question

Comment: Sorry i edited the question again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From
$$e^x= 1 + x+ \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$$
one gets that
$$
f(x)=e^{-x}= 1 - x+ \dfrac{x^2}{2!} - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots
$$ giving
$$
f(x)=xe^{-x}= x - x^2+ \dfrac{x^3}{2!} - \dfrac{x^4}{3!} + \dfrac{x^5}{4!}+\cdots
$$ or

> $$
> f(x)=xe^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}.
> $$

Comment: Why doesn't n=0 work? the left side is 0 but hte right side is not?

Comment: The right side is also equal to zero at $x=0$:$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}=x \times \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$ which is $0\times 1$ at $x=0$.

Comment: And what if we took $T_0$ at x=0? That means I plug in 0 for both n and x right?